# custom summaryType callback when finish

Tags: jqgrid

Hello in my colModel I have function `summaryType(val,name,record)` with this content:

```
val = record[name]*100+Number(val);
return val;
```

But my val is a flaot number, the value of val is 42.7893534 I want display this number with only 2 decimal I do `return val.toFixed(1);` and in out I have 42.78 and not 42.79 !! How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function moeda2float(moeda){

   moeda = moeda.replace(".","");

   moeda = moeda.replace(",",".");

   return parseFloat(moeda);

}
```

Comment: Hello thank you this doesn't work... My problem is that: I want to tcheck when the summaryType function is finish to calculate the sum... then I can apply the return val.toFixed(2);